# Can you use a rest parameter as a destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example, here's a method to copy an object:

```
const o = {
  hello: 'hello',
  world: 'world'
}

const { hello, world } = o;
const o2 = { hello, world };
```

I'd like to use a rest parameter to simplify this, but it doesn't seem possibly (unless I'm just messing up the syntax):

```
const o2 = { ...Object.keys(o) }
```

Is this simply not possible, or do I have the syntax wrong? If it's not possible, is there another way to duplicate an object in ES6, other than `Object.assign`?

```
var o2 = {};
Object.assign(o2, o);
```

Only reason I don't like the `Object.assign` approach is because it feels "mutaty" and more stateful than a more functional approach like `{ ...Object.keys(o) }`. Thoughts?

Comment: Per the description at MDN, `Object.assign()` does this: **The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.**.  Why is this not what you want for making a copy?  Sounds like it does exactly what is needed for a plain object.  It's no more or less stateful than anything else.  It makes a copy.

Comment: @jfriend00, you're 100% right. That's an error on my part. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making this an answer per your request:

Per the [description at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), `Object.assign()` does this: **The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.**.

Why is this not what you want for making a copy?  Sounds like it does exactly what is needed for a plain object.  It's no more or less stateful than anything else.  It makes a copy.

---

FYI, you could make your self a copy function:

```
Object.myCopy = function(source) {
    return Object.assign({}, source);
}
```

Comment: right, thanks. My mistake was that I didn't realize it would return the object. I thought you first had to declare an object, and then mutate it afterwards with `Object.assign` (changing it in place), which I wasn't a fan of.

Comment: @JoshBeam, according to the examples on MDN, that's exactly what's happening. The target object is _modified_ and returned. See the "Merging objects" example in particular. I guess if you use `var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);` you've sort of hidden the mutation by instantiating an anonymous empty object inline, but `assign` is still mutating that empty object. That said, there's little to be gained by being dogmatic about this, so what you have is probably good enough.

Comment: @DavidS - And, the way that `Object.assign()` works allows it to be more flexible because it can either fill up a new empty object (by just passing in `{}` as you've shown) or it can copy properties into an existing object that may already have other properties (e.g. merge).  There should be no concern about "mutating" an empty object.  No matter how any copy function is written, it's going to create a new empty object and then fill it up.  This just gives you the option of starting with your own object if you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [ES7 proposal for an *object spread element*](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread), which pretty much works like the array spread operator:

```
var o1 = {foo: 42}:
var o2 = {...o1};
// o2 is now a shallow copy of o1
```

As you can see in the proposal, this is really just syntactic sugar for `Object.assign` and is equivalent to

```
var o2 = Object.assign({}, o1);
```

---

The same proposal also defines an object rest element, so this would work as well:

```
var {...o2} = o1;
```

Comment: Ah yes I think this is exactly what I would've been looking for! Interesting stuff.